# EKEventStore throwing error on saving EKEvents suddenly in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ekevent, ekeventstore

I am creating a custom calendar and was connecting it to the local calendar.

Everything was working fine, but I think after I changed the type of the device, EKEventStore started to not work.

However, all the sudden, the EKEvent is not saving and I get

> "Issue sending EkEvent"

code to createNewEvent

```
func createNewEKEvent(from event:Events) -> EKEvent {
    let newEvent = EKEvent(eventStore: eventStore)
    newEvent.title = event.title
    newEvent.startDate = event.startDate
    newEvent.endDate = event.endDate
    newEvent.notes = event.notes
    do {
        try eventStore.save(newEvent, span: .thisEvent)
    } catch {
        print("Issue sending EKEvent")
    }
    return newEvent
}
```

If anyone know anything about this please help.. thank you

Comment: display your error log

Comment: I don't get an Error log.. this is all I get

2018-05-31 16:26:14.147400+0900 ScheduleMe[2947:60013] [MC] Reading from private effective user settings. Issue sending EKEvent